# How to pause a TeamCity build from a build step of another build

Tags: build, configuration, teamcity

In TeamCity I have 2 related builds having different triggers.

While the first build is executing I'd like to pause the second build.

So my idea was to have a build step in build 1 to pause build 2. And then another build step to activate it again.

Is this possible in TeamCity? Or should I use a different approach?

Comment: why do you need that? and should build2 pause build1 ?

Comment: The reason: Build 1 is manually triggered and executes a DB migration. Build 2 is triggered on each check-in and executes tests using the DB.

Comment: maybe you have to reject test job if migration is in progress (as one of pre-test cases), and add an additional  dependency trigger to a test job, so it will be forced to start after migration...

Comment: Can I do this pre-test condition in TeamCity?

Comment: in a standard way - no. I thimk you can install groovy plugin (for example) and write a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding PowerShell build step sending a web request to the TeamCity API.

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(($($Username):$($Password)")))
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" }

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri "http://rzaplp4:8088/app/rest/buildTypes/$($BuildId)/paused" -Body "true" -ContentType "text/plain" -Headers $headers > $null
```